# NSFetchRequest - entity - unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, nsfetchrequest

I am currently working with Swift 2.0 and created a new "Master-Detail Application" in X-Code. I need that when the user clicks the BarButtomItem, a new View appears requesting a text field that will do a search in the internet. 
The code to open the ViewController is as follows:

```
    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {

    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let vc : ISBNRequest = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myISBN") as! ISBNRequest

    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Once the user enters the text, and the search is finished, I need to add the results into to the TableView. To do this, Im calling an update function from the view Controller:

Function in ViewController:

```
@IBAction func buscarLibro(sender: AnyObject) {
    print ("aqui estamos")
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    let mvc :MasterViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myMVC") as! MasterViewController

    var titulo : String = String()
    var autores : [String] = [String]()
    var portada : UIImage = UIImage()

    let isbnTxt = ISBN.text!
    let urls = "https://openlibrary.org/api/books?jscmd=data&format=json&bibkeys=ISBN"+isbnTxt
    let url = NSURL(string: urls)
    let datos:NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    if (datos == nil) {
        //No hacer nada
        print("datos nil")
    } else {
        //let texto = NSString(data:datos!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        //self.textView.text = texto! as String
        print("empieza busqueda")
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(datos!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves)
            let dico1 = json as! NSDictionary
            print(dico1.allKeys)
            var tmp = dico1["ISBN"+isbnTxt]
            if (tmp != nil && tmp is NSDictionary) {
                let dico2 = tmp as! NSDictionary
                tmp = dico2["authors"]
                if (tmp != nil && tmp is NSArray) {
                    let dico3 =  tmp as! NSArray

                    titulo = (dico2["title"] as! NSString as String)
                    for id in dico3 {
                        print(id["name"])
                        autores.append(id["name"] as! NSString as String)
                    }
                    let cover = dico2["cover"]
                    if (cover != nil && cover is NSDictionary) {
                        let covers = cover as! NSDictionary
                        let url = NSURL(string: covers["medium"] as! NSString as String)
                        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) {
                            portada = UIImage(data: data)!
                        }

                    }
                    print("LIBRO:" + titulo)
                    let libro : Libro = Libro(nombre : titulo,autores: autores, portada: portada)
                    mvc.libros.append(libro)
                    for x in mvc.libros {
                        print (x.nombre)
                    }
                    mvc.actualiza(libro)

                }
            }
        } catch _ {
        }
    }
}
```

The mvc.actualiza function does the following:

```
func actualiza (libro:Libro) {
    let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
    let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context)

    // If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
    // Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
    newManagedObject.setValue(libro as? AnyObject, forKey: "timeStamp")

    // Save the context.
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
}
```

When executing the first line, in crashes here:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
```

And I am getting the following error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I missing to include in the transition from one view controller to another one?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like `self.managedObjectContext` has not been initialised. You could try putting this before the faulting line to check:

```
print("managedObjectContext: \(self.managedObjectContext)")
```

Comment: in case it is not initialised, how could I initialize it? @emrys57

Comment: it is not initialized. The thing is that when it loads the first time, it is initialized... but when I open the other view and then want to come back to the main one, the managedObjectContext variable is no longer initialized. How could I initialize it then? @emrys57

Comment: I can't see how to answer that without knowing more about the controllers. Perhaps you should ask a new question showing different code.

Comment: everything remained the same as it is when creating a Master Detail Application in XCode. The only thing I changed is the ViewController in between to ask for the textfield to search. The problem is that when closing the ViewController the conext is nil